# Snap.SVG - Manipulate $(this) element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I have a problem with Snap.SVG and animation of multiple SVG elements. 
I want to change path on hover, but i have many same SVG in html.

HTML:

```js
   

var svg = $('.svg-wave');
var s = Snap(svg);

var simpleCup = Snap.select('.svg-wave-normal');
var fancyCup = Snap.select('.svg-wave-hover');

var simpleCupPoints = simpleCup.node.getAttribute('d');
var fancyCupPoints = fancyCup.node.getAttribute('d');

svg.mouseenter(function() {
  simpleCup.animate({
    d: fancyCupPoints
  }, 600);
}).mouseleave(function() {
  simpleCup.animate({
    d: simpleCupPoints
  }, 600);
});
```

```css
svg .svg-wave-hover {opacity: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <svg class="svg-wave" width="240" height="120" viewBox="0 0 240 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path class="svg-wave-normal" d="M108.5,114.8C71.7,114.8,62.7,117,0,117h217C151,117,146.2,114.8,108.5,114.8" fill="#69c6d3"></path>
                            <path class="svg-wave-hover"  d="M108.5,0C71.7,0,62.7,117,0,117h217C151,117,146.2,0,108.5,0" fill="#69c6d3"></path>
                        </svg>
  </div>
<div class="item">
  <svg class="svg-wave" width="240" height="120" viewBox="0 0 240 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path class="svg-wave-normal" d="M108.5,114.8C71.7,114.8,62.7,117,0,117h217C151,117,146.2,114.8,108.5,114.8" fill="#69c6d3"></path>
                            <path class="svg-wave-hover"  d="M108.5,0C71.7,0,62.7,117,0,117h217C151,117,146.2,0,108.5,0" fill="#69c6d3"></path>
                        </svg>
  </div>
<div class="item">
  <svg class="svg-wave" width="240" height="120" viewBox="0 0 240 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path class="svg-wave-normal" d="M108.5,114.8C71.7,114.8,62.7,117,0,117h217C151,117,146.2,114.8,108.5,114.8" fill="#69c6d3"></path>
                            <path class="svg-wave-hover"  d="M108.5,0C71.7,0,62.7,117,0,117h217C151,117,146.2,0,108.5,0" fill="#69c6d3"></path>
                        </svg>
</div>
```

The problem is that when i hover last SVG, it animate the first one. 
Can someone help me to change mouseenter/leave to work from $(this) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest a way without using JQuery firstly, as it's not really necessary.

I would change your css to make the hover path `display: none`, rather than `opacity: 0`, as display none means that events will pass through fine, whereas opacity will capture them. Or you could reorder the paths, so the hove paths come first.

```
var normalWaves = Snap.selectAll('.svg-wave-normal');
var normalPoints = Snap.select('.svg-wave-normal').attr('d');
var hoverPoints = Snap.select('.svg-wave-hover').attr('d');

normalWaves.forEach(function( wave ) {
  wave.mouseover(function() {
    this.animate({
      d: hoverPoints
    }, 600); 
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    this.animate({
      d: normalPoints
    }, 600);
  });
});

svg .svg-wave-hover { display: none; }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qmxnorg/)